# show pdf with flutter on android

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello the code below displays a pdf file with flutter consult the aforementioned pub package but when I run the code on android do I have the following error? how can I solve this problem on the above line: PDFDocument document = waitit PDFDocument.fromAsset (fullPath);

**Package**: `advance_pdf_viewer`

**Error:**

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error parsing asset file!
E/flutter (32201): #0      PDFDocument.fromAsset (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/document.dart:66:7)
```

**Flutter Code**

```
    Directory documentDirectory;
   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
     documentDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
   }
   else{
       documentDirectory=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   }
  String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
  String fullPath = "$documentPath/example.pdf";
  print("FullPath: "+fullPath);
  File file = new File.fromUri(Uri.parse(fullPath));
  PDFDocument document = await PDFDocument.fromFile(file);
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PdfPreviewScreen(file: document,path:fullPath,rp: rptemp,)
   ));
```

**Exception:**

```
Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error parsing asset file!
E/flutter ( 4693): #0      PDFDocument.fromAsset (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/document.dart:66:7)
```

Comment: You use weak plugin, try use this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer it more powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **loading pdf from a file path** and **NOT an asset file**(which is stored in along with the app data) so u need to use that particular method of the plugin not the one to load pdf from asset which u are using in ur code right now.

```
File file = new File.fromUri(Uri.parse(fullPath));
PDFDocument doc = await PDFDocument.fromFile(file);
```

Your code should look like this:

```
Directory documentDirectory;
   if (Platform.isAndroid) {
     documentDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
   }
   else{
       documentDirectory=await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
   }
  String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
  String fullPath = "$documentPath/example.pdf";
  print("FullPath: "+fullPath);
  File file = new File.fromUri(Uri.parse(fullPath));
  PDFDocument document = await PDFDocument.fromFile(file);
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PdfPreviewScreen(file: document,path:fullPath,rp: rptemp,)
   ));
```

Comment: it doesn't matter what device u r on. you were using                  .fromAsset but u need to use .fromFile

Comment: i'm use .fromfile, this happens on all android devices

Comment: can u post the error that u get after using .fromFile ?

Comment: this is error: Unhandled Exception: Exception: Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error parsing asset file!
E/flutter ( 4693): #0      PDFDocument.fromAsset (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/document.dart:66:7)